# React Native: call a function after getting the permission

Tags: react-native

I just need to call a function after getting the location permission.
This is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.samplePermissionRequest();
    alert('componentDidMount');
  }

  samplePermissionRequest=()=>{
    async function requestLocationPermission() {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            'title': 'Cool Location tracking App Permission',
            'message': 'This Cool App needs access to your location '
          }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          this.justStart();
          alert("You can use the app");
        } else {
          alert("You can not use the app");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
    requestLocationPermission();
  }

  justStart=()=>{
      alert("start with permission");
  }
```

When I run this code, I only get the dialog of the first alert ( alert('componentDidMount') ).

If I remove the line "this.justStart();", then the second alert is displayed as well. So the problem is that "this.justStart();" doesn't work.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` will be `undefined` inside your `requestLocationPermission` function.
Hence `this.justStart()` will throw type error which will be caught by your try/catch statement.

Solution 1,

Bind `this` when you call `requestLocationPermission`.

> requestLocationPermission.call(this);

Solution 2,

Remove function `requestLocationPermission` and directly use `samplePermissionRequest` instead of using inner function and calling it again.

```
async samplePermissionRequest = () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Cool Location tracking App Permission',
          'message': 'This Cool App needs access to your location '
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        this.justStart();
        alert("You can use the app");
      } else {
        alert("You can not use the app");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

you have to work with Promise object, you can change your code like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.requestLocationPermission().then(
        alert('componentDidMount')
    );
}


async requestLocationPermission() {
    return PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
            'title': 'Cool Location tracking App Permission',
            'message': 'This Cool App needs access to your location '
        }
    ).then(granted => {
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            this.justStart();
            alert("You can use the app");
        } else {
            alert("You can not use the app");
        }
    }).catch(e => console.warn(e));
}
```

on Promise that async methods return you can use .then and .catch